# Axios patch doesn't get baseURL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, patch

I'm trying to change my Axios patch baseURL but I don't know why when I call this
stageReceiver method it still getting a default baseURL (the one where my npm run serve is listening and serving my app).

```
import axios from "axios";

const getSingleSenders = baseURL =>
  axios
    .get("/single/senders", {baseURL: baseURL})
    .then(({ data }) => ({ senders: data }))

const stageReceiver = (receiverId, baseURL, stagedPayload) =>
  axios
    .patch("/single/receivers/" + receiverId + "/staged", {
        baseURL: baseURL,
        payload: stagedPayload,
        Headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
      })
    .then(({ data }) => ({ receiver: data }))

export default {
    getSingleSenders,
    getSingleSender,
    stageReceiver
};
```

When I call function when needed with lets say newBaseURL="http://172.17.0.13:8080/test":

```
const stagedResult = await connectionService.stageReceiver(id, newBaseURL, connectionPayload)
```

If I check on the browser I can see that the request is getting 404 with the wrong URL of my Vue dev instance (where my npm run serve is listening):

http://localhost:8082/single/receivers/id/staged

Instead

http://172.17.0.13:8080/test/single/receivers/id/staged

The other method getSingleSenders with get is working without any issue and it get the baseURL correctly written.
I'm missing something but I don't know what. I hope the question is clear enough.
Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: I don't see a reason for that except that newBaseURL is not what you expect. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. You can try to isolate the problem by hardcoding baseURL value, as well as replacing `patch` with `get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your config as third parameter as stated in the documentation:

```
const stageReceiver = (receiverId, baseURL, stagedPayload) =>
    axios
      .patch(
         "/single/receivers/" + receiverId + "/staged",
         stagedPayload,
         {
            baseURL: baseURL,
            Headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
         }
      )
      .then(({ data }) => ({ receiver: data }));
```